# Filter mobile numberd using SQL (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
call(varchar) duration(int)     mobile_num(varchar)

outgoing       78              111113
incoming       5               111113
incoming       12              111112
outgoing       13              111112
incoming       75              111113
```

SQL query to return the output of mobile numbers

```
conditions:

the number should have both incoming and outgoing :
duration should be (total_outgoing > total_incoming) :
The order of output is in ascending order.
```

Output is:

```
Number 
111112
```

The output is 111112 as the total outgoing call duration is 13 and the total incoming call duration is 12.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and what issue you are facing ?

Comment: What the expected output ?

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: @Elikill58  list of mobile numbers that satisfy the conditions above in ascending order.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

```
select mobile_num
from
  (select mobile_num,
          sum(case when call = 'outgoing' then duration end) total_outgoing,
          sum(case when call = 'incoming' then duration end) total_incoming
  from t1
  group by mobile_num) t
where total_outgoing > total_incoming
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09d3f939f2d46ed4209fcb4c065f2019)

Comment: is it in mysql?

Comment: yes see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3536fb259ca08ab7fcfda7694568008d

Comment: Subquery is obviously excess. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f66d13020e28fd279693d62976677bd1

Comment: Yes HAVING is a more beautiful solution.